# Error when trying to use switch() to return a NULL value in if else statement in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, null

I have an if statement with a null result, but I keep receiving errors when trying to run the code.

For example, my df has two numeric columns with values ranging from 0 to 100. I want to create a new column based on the following psuedo code:

ifelse (df$column1 == 0, NULL, df$column2/df$column1)

I have tried [switch()](https://www.r-bloggers.com/use-switch-instead-of-ifelse-to-return-a-null/) but when I do that I receive an error:
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Switch code:

```
df$column3 = switch((df$column1[i] != 0) + 1, 
             NULL, 
             df$column2/df$column1)
```

When I tried putting that into a for loop to look at each record separately, I get another error (similar to what I had when I tried the ifelse():
   Error in df$column3[i] <- n : 
   replacement has length zero

for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
             n = switch((df$column1[i] != 0) + 1, 
               NULL, 
               df$column2/df$column1)
             df$column3[i] = n 

      }
```

How can I adjust this to set a NULL in the column if it does not satisfy certain criteria.

Any advice would be super helpful please! Thank you!

Comment: `NULL` is not a legal value in most vectors.  Use `NA` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your pseudocode is basically there?

Here's an example with the `iris` dataset that comes with R:

```
iris$newcol = ifelse(
  iris$Sepal.Length < 5, 
  NA_real_, 
  iris$Sepal.Length/iris$Sepal.Width
  )
iris
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't mention that I have 2 scenarios. This works for the 1st one, but when I tried it with the 2nd one w/ a date as the "else" result, I am getting a non-date in that field.  The issue with this code is that because I am using a date, the format of the field is converted to a character b/c of the null so the date in the "else" part comes out like 18345. I tried fifelse, but I get errors that the NA_real_ is not the same class. I'm stuck with converting the character "date" to a readable date. When I try to cast that field as a date with as.Date() I get an origin error.

Comment: Maybe you just want to use the logical `NA`? R will try to coerce the type of missing value for you if you use the logical one. I am in the habit of specifying the type but you don't have to. `library('lubridate');
dates = c(
  '2020-01-01',
  '2020-01-15',
  '2020-01-30'
);
dates = ymd(dates); dates[3] = NA`

Comment: Thank you! This is my code:  df$newDateCol = ifelse(df$anotherCol == "Yes", <need a null here>, Sys.Date())  . This is where I have tried the fifelse, switch and rearraged them etc.  When I tried using NA in the null section I get: 18292... when I use fifelse, I get an error: 'yes' is of type logical but 'no' is of type double.

Comment: Maybe just fill the column with `Sys.Date()` first and then replace? 
`df = data.frame(
  x = sample(
    c('Yes', 'No', NA),
    size = 10,
    replace = TRUE
  ),
  y = Sys.Date()
);
df$y[which(df$x == 'Yes')] = NA`

Comment: Perfect!! I think this will work!! Thank you so much!